# Можно ли вынести функцию из views.py в Django?

Tags: python, django

Views.py со временем растет,появилась необходимость создания большой функции и хотелось бы создать отдельный файл для неё. Как это лучше реализовать и можно ли вообще?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно создавать модуль с любым названием и размещать где угодно. views.py это просто негласное соглашение, сама же джанга не запрещает.

Если приложение сложное, то логику нужно раскидывать по другим файлам так, как это делается в обычных проектах, вынося во вьюхи, для исполнения, только лишь высокоуровневый функционал.

В таком виде все функции вьюх(если это функции), будут достаточно маленькими. С классами аналогично.

Answer (score 0):

Можно. Вы можете вынести хоть весь функционал в отдельный модуль, и вызвать , передавая в него request и получая готовую страницу.

Вы так же можете выносить вивы в отдельные файлы, просто тогда в файле urls ловиться запрос будет приблизительно вот так:
url(r'^ссылка/$', название_модуля_с_вьюхой.название_вьюхи, name='имя'),